Change button background color when clicking on it (Wix website)
I would like to have the following conditions regarding my button "#button5" on my wix website:

Standard color: white;
When the user is on the page (contact), the button color will change to red;
When the user leaves this page, the button color will return to white.

Can you help me?
I couldn't do anything because I'm new to the platform

From ADI: Changing the Style of Your Button:

You can change and customize the style of your button.
To change the style of your button:

Hover over the button on your site.
Hover over the Buttons label.

Click Design to select a style for your button.
Select one of the colors from your Site Colors to change the color of your button.





Note: If you have 2 buttons in your ADI section, the style of your second button is based on the settings of your first button.


